AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'. while Web scraping
I get the following error when trying to AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
    import numpy as np

    headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
     }

     html = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BSPAX", headers=headers)
     soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
     A1=[float(soup.find("fin-streamer", class_="Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").text)]


soup.find() did not find any matching element, therefore it returned None, and then you tried to access its .text attribute.

looking at the HTML source code in Chrome I do see the following : 

Yes that element is in Chrome, because Chrome is a real browser that can process javascript.  But requests cannot process javascript.

The actual problem was that yahoo finance recently updated their webpage  (within the last week).  The old web page had ""  and the new  webpage has "19.22"

Don't change the question into an answer.

"Don't change the question into an answer. – gre_gor" apologies didn't realized one is not permitted to do so will keep that in mind. No worries.

That indicates that BeautifulSoup is unable to find the element. Please consult the documentation for this.

If find() can’t find anything, it returns None:


Although the answer given by bjdesa is right, I would like to increment it.
It means the find method is returning None, the error is happening here:
A1=[float(soup.find("fin-streamer", class_="Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").text)]

This is returning None
soup.find("fin-streamer", class_="Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)")

So you can access text, because a None object has no text attribute.

Although the answer given by bjdesa - wrong person I think

Many thanks for the many useless comments of what I was already aware of here is the solution:
Replace:
    A1=[float(soup.find("fin-streamer", class_="Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").text)]

With:
    A1=[float(soup.find("fin-streamer", class_="livePrice svelte-mgkamr").text)]

